# Извлечь целое число из строки DataFrame

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dataframe

Необходимо из текста, содержащегося в ячейке DataFrame вычленить численную часть и заменить тест на нее.
Пример содержимого ячейки: '1560 MHz', на выходе должно быть: 1560.
Написал простую функцию:

```py
def pd_str_to_int(a, ind=0):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = int(a[i].split()[ind])
    return a
```

Вопрос, можно ли как-то тоже самое сделать более оптимально и средствами библиотеки Pandas?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример данных:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": ["1560 MHz", np.nan, "aaa", "", "blah 10 12 13 blah"]})
```

```
In [304]: df
Out[304]:
                  col
0            1560 MHz
1                 NaN
2                 aaa
3
4  blah 10 12 13 blah
```

решение - воспользуйтесь [Series.str.extract()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df["num"] = pd.to_numeric(df["col"].str.extract(r"\b(\d+)\b")[0], errors="coerce")
```

результат:

```
In [314]: df
Out[314]:
                  col     num
0            1560 MHz  1560.0
1                 NaN     NaN
2                 aaa     NaN
3                         NaN
4  blah 10 12 13 blah    10.0

In [315]: df.dtypes
Out[315]:
col     object
num    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Благодарю! Проблема решена